# Shortest Program in c++

Tags: c++

I came across this code recently that compiles, but runs with segmentation fault(g++). 
Here's the original link from topcoder
[topcoder profile](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=MemberProfile&cr=22689214&tab=alg)

```
#include <iostream>
int main = ( std::cout << "Hello world!\n", 42  );
```

This also compiles

```
int main=0;
```

Can someone explain what's happening in this program. Using g++

Comment: What do you consider to be the shortest? The shortest C++ program is 0 characters long. Are those 2 different programs? Or 2 parts of the same program?

Comment: There is just so much wrong here that I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @Falmarri:      Shortest executable program

Comment: Neither of these is a valid program. If your implementation happens to generate an executable or allows either to run, that's an unfortunate consequence of the implementation (and of the fact that you used a language which inherently cannot check every possible error condition).

Comment: I know that there are supposedly no bad questions, but this is really useless.

Comment: @ John Dibling: A please close/delete as pointless option :-)

Comment: @Martin:  I suppose "Close as stupid question" would be too politically incorrect. :)

Comment: @John: Then I suggest the category: `Cerebrum Flectuntur`

Comment: @John Dibling: I just posted this question because it was from a topcoder member ranked 121

Comment: Sure this question is garbage, but I'm curious now -- let's say a variable named var1 was defined inside main like so, it seems to be a valid program but what is going on? 
```int main()
{ int var1 = ( std::cout << "Hello world!\n", 42  ); }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is all silly games.  Both programs violate the requirement "a program shall contain a global function called `main`" (3.6.1p1).  Those programs may fool some compilers because they define a symbol `main`, but that symbol is not a function at all!  No wonder at least one of them crashes when the runtime tries to use that `main` symbol as a function.

The shortest valid C++03 program in a hosted implementation:

```
int main(){}
```

Comment: It doesn't result in undefined behavior, main may return nothing, in which case zero is returned.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler add a `return 0;` if one is missing ? or does something among those lines ?

Comment: Note this automatic `return 0` only happens for `main`.  Forgot about this exception (which should not actually be used). Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be used? It has well defined behaviour; I can't see a disadvantage myself.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry, the code you posted is not a valid C++ program. A valid C++ program must have an entry point that is a function of name `main` in the global scope with one of the signatures dictated by the standard. The shortest valid program in C++ is:

```
int main(){}
```

Comment: Don't forget the newline. :-)

Comment: According to the preprocessing grammar described in Section 16, tokens must be followed by a newline, or the translation unit is syntactically invalid.  Of course, most compilers will accept files without final newline anyway.

Comment: @Billy: 2.1/1: "If a source file that is not empty does not end in a new-line character, or ends in a new-line character immediately preceded by a backslash character, the behavior is undefined". So depends whether you want a valid program, or a valid program with defined behavior.

Comment: @Steve @aschepler: *Bill runs and starts looking through his codebase for that....*

Comment: @R.. @Billy ONeal  In older/current versions of C/C++ technically you need the newline character (though most compilers will not complain) **but** In C++0x this restriction has been removed.

Comment: @Martin: Oh, such a relief. :)

Answer (score 7):

The following code will work:

`char main[]="\xb4\x00\xcd\x16\xcd\x20";`

This assigns the machine level code of the following to the symbol main, which is a char array.

```
mov ah,0
int 16h ; Wait for a keyboard input i.e getch();
int 20h ;  Exit to DOS
```

Compiler sees a symbol main and compiles the code properly. It passes the control to the symbol main (which is the default action of a C/C++ compiler), where it finds the machine code. Hence, it executes properly.

Answer (score 6):

If you're really interested in the size of the executable the number of lines of code really isn't important, at least not to me. What matters is machine instructions and the size of the file. Here are two really great links:

- [A Whirlwind Tutorial](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux.
- [Tiny PE](http://www.phreedom.org/solar/code/tinype/) (Portable Executable, the win32 and x64 executable file format).

In short, the smallest possible executable does not necessarily depend on the number of lines of code but many other things besides. This is some seriously interesting engineering, in my opinion.

Comment: @Muggen thanks... I think the ELF one might be slightly out of date; I couldn't get as far as them before linux just plain refused. Things might have changed for x64. If I get any free time this year without exams, work, bids or whatever I'm going to have a go myself...!

Comment: While these links are interesting, I think the step of going from 372 bytes to 45 bytes is of very little practical interest, while steps that reduce seemingly trivial but *useful* programs from 50k to 5k on disk or from 500k to 24k resident size are a lot more interesting.

Comment: @R I don't disagree with you. I merely posted them for interest's sake.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest c++ programm is :

`int main(){}`

output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6xiK.png